# What should I feed a pig to make it my pet?

Tags: cube-world

I just started to play CubeWorld and I do know you can tame animals by giving them food. They become some kind of followers and help you in fights.

I want to tame the first thing I met (a pig) but can't figure out what to give him to get him as a pet. I tried what I had on me (carrots) but it doesn't work.

What do I need to find?

Comment: how can you be playing Cube World? I thought it was still in development

Comment: It just came out, and is awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This site](http://wiki.cubeworldforum.org/index.php/Taming), though I can't be 100% sure of its accuracy, suggests that pigs need to be fed **pumpkin mash** to be tamed.  This is corroborated on the [Cube World Forums](http://cubeworldforum.org/topic/3781-list-of-foods-each-pet-eats-in-cube-world-guide-spoilers/).

Answer (score -1):

You can feed it pumpkin mash. There is a full list here - http://gamewise.co/games/46604/Cube-World/Mobs/Taming

Answer (score -2):

You feed it pumpkin mash to make it your pet.

Comment: While [apparently correct](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/122736/88), you post doesn't add anything new to this question. Please concentrate your efforts on [unanswered questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/unanswered) and/or be a bit more verbose